# ffmpeg - H264 vs. H265 codec parameters?

Tags: ffmpeg

When i try to run following command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel info -threads 0 -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -framerate 60 -i image.png -start_number 000000 -apply_trc bt709 -framerate 60 -i seq1.%06d.exr -start_number 000000 -apply_trc bt709 -framerate 60 -i seq2.%06d.exr -r 60 -preset medium -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -tune fastdecode -c:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -vbr 5 -shortest -strict experimental -sn -vsync 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 62914560 -movflags +faststart -x264-params high-tier=0:pmode=1:wpp=1:tune=zerolatnecy,fastdecode::bitrate=62914:fps=60:keyint=600:min-keyint=60:vbv-bufsize=62914:vbv-maxrate=62914:scenecut=00 -filter_complex "[2:v]crop=5120:2560:0:0, scale=4096:1152, rotate=0[input_num0];[1:v][input_num0]overlay=0:0[output_num0];[3:v]crop=5120:2560:0:0, scale=4096:1152, rotate=0[input_num1];[1:v][input_num1]overlay=0:0[output_num1];[output_num1][output_num0] vstack [result]" -map "[result]:0 -map "0:0"" output.mp4 2>&1 | tee -a log_file.log
```

I get the following error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] Error parsing option 'high-tier = 0'.
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] Error parsing option 'pmode = 1'.
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] Error parsing option 'wpp = 1'.
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] Error parsing option 'tune = zerolatnecy,fastdecode'.
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] Error parsing option ':bitrate = 62914'.
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] using SAR=9/16
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] MB rate (2211840) > level limit (2073600)
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fd8fa003600] profile High, level 5.2
```

Is it because those parameters are not recognized by H264 or?..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of those options don't belong to x264.

Use

```
-b:v 62914560 -bufsize 62914560 -maxrate 62914560 -movflags +faststart -x264-params keyint=600:min-keyint=60:scenecut=00
```